# How to remove 3M Scotch Super 77 from finished hardwood surface

Tags: cleaning, adhesive, upholstery

I decided to upholster my wooden dining chairs. These chairs were 100% hardwood and finished in glossy polyurethane (i.e. had no padding)

I just finished working on one chair and realized that I had over-sprayed the glue on chair legs, in areas I didn't plan to cover.

The glue I used is 3M Scotch Super 77 spray can.

Is there a way I could remove the glue from the surface of wood without damaging wood surface or surface finish?

There are some fibers stuck to the glue on wood surface. glue is not visible in picture, but it can be felt when touching wood surface.

[image]

Comment: No real need to indicate "Update 1", "Update 2", etc. If someone asks a question, do put the answer in your OP, and add a comment with an `@username` to let them know you've answered - that's all it takes. Well done, BTW, including a picture without prompting!

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna have to play and see.  Spray Super 77 on some scrap and use it for testing.

Then roll through every chemical in the house - canola oil (one kind of food oil will suffice), each kind of alcohol you have (no no, not Bud and Jack Daniels, I mean ethanol, isopropyl etc.), then each kind of mineral spirit you have: gasoline, paint thinner, naptha, acetone (aka nail polish remover), etc.

Once you identify some winners, try them on an inconspicuous area of that finish to see which ones if any attack the finish.

Answer (score 0):

Various solvents may work. Test in the most inconspicuous area to be sure they don't also affect your finish, but cured polyurethane is pretty tough, if it is actually polyurethane.

Specific on-web mentions of success with this product include Acetone (*a.k.a.* nail polish remover) and Mineral Sprits (*a.k.a.* paint thinner.) Others may work. Of those two, mineral sprits is generally less aggressive to cured finishes than acetone.

Comment: I am concerned if any of those solvents can affect the polyurethane surface finish

Comment: ..which is why you **test on an inconspicuous area** - up under the seat on the inside of the leg, or on the bottom of the stretchers. If it's polyurethane, paint thinner won't bother it at all, in my experience.